# Debugging Missing Label in WinForm Application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, label

I was developing a WinForm application for a class and I ran into a bug that I can't seem to find the root of. When I run the application everything works except for an error label that was supposed to come up with incorrect user input. At first I thought I had written the event handler for it wrong, so I stopped hiding it at startup but the label is still missing. I'm not sure if I'm missing something in some back-end file or if I'm just missing something really obvious.

This is the function that creates the label.

```
private void InitializeErrorLabel()
{
    int width = 200, height = 13,
        anchorY = this.Label.Location.Y - this.Label.Size.Height - 3;

    // Initialize Component
    this.ErrorLabel.AutoSize = true;
    this.ErrorLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold,
        System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    this.ErrorLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    this.ErrorLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point((XSize - width) / 2, (anchorY - height));
    this.ErrorLabel.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top;
    this.ErrorLabel.Name = "ErrorLabel";
    this.ErrorLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(width, height);
    this.ErrorLabel.Text = "Invalid User ID. Please try again!";
    return;
}
```

and this is the function that initializes my controls:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.UserInput = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    this.SwitchMajor = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
    this.SwitchToCS = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
    this.SwitchToCE = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
    this.KeepMajor = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
    this.AcceptValues = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.Label = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.ErrorLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.SuspendLayout();

    // Initialize Components
    this.InitializeLabel();
    this.InitializeMainWindow();
    this.InitializeUserInput();
    this.InitializeSwitchMajorBtn();
    this.InitializeChangeToCSBtn();
    this.InitializeChangeToCEBtn();
    this.InitializeAcceptValuesBtn();
    this.InitializeErrorLabel();

    this.ResumeLayout();
    this.PerformLayout();
    return;
}
```

Again, not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In what control are you adding your errorlabel ?

A normal label initialization should look like

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label ErrorLabel;

this.ErrorLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.ErrorLabel);

this.ErrorLabel.AutoSize = true;
this.ErrorLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 59);
this.ErrorLabel.Name = "ErrorLabel";
this.ErrorLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 13);
this.ErrorLabel.TabIndex = 69;
this.ErrorLabel.Text = "Address 2";
this.ErrorLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

**Important**

The label must be added to a control like my line three. Your control can be a form in your case. Its a groupbox in my case and the group box itself must be added to myform and myform must be visible .

```
 this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.ErrorLabel);
```

Comment: Yes. That's actually what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a place where you're adding the label to the form's collection of controls:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.ErrorLabel);
```

If it's not a member of the `Controls` collection, you won't see it.

Related to that, I wouldn't be surprised if the other buttons, checkboxes, etc you're defining are not showing up on the form either, for the same reason.

Normally this would be taken care of by the `Designer.cs` file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an obvious answer, but it totally went over my head. I verified that my code had the `this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.ErrorLabel);` like others have mentioned here. I couldn't figure out why I wasn't seeing my label. My label was an asterisk `*`, and in the designer window, I size it pretty small, but I was able to see the `*` in the designer window. Turns out I just had to increase it's area in the designer window since it was to small when I actually rendered the App.